# $\int \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {x^{7/2}} dx$ without using trigonometry?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\int \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {x^{7/2}} dx$$

Is there any way to find the answer without using trigonometry, like [this](http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP5702007i95faihdc1b6000034ae2b8abef7agbd?MSPStoreType=image/png&s=21&w=564&h=1485?)?

**Hint by Parth Thakkat**:

$$\int \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {x^{7/2}} dx$$

$$ = \int \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {x^{1/2}} \cdot \dfrac{dx} {x^{3}}$$

$$ = \int \sqrt{1+\dfrac 1 x} \cdot \dfrac{dx} {x^{3}}$$

Take $t^2 = 1 + \dfrac 1 x$

and note that $ \dfrac 1 x = t^2 - 1$

**More Hint**:

$t^2 = 1 + \dfrac 1 x$

$\implies 2tdt = -\dfrac 1 {x^2}dx$

**Next**

$$ = \int t dx/x^3$$

**Since** $dx = -2tx^2 dt$

$$= \int t(-2t)(t^2-1) dt$$
$$ = -2\int t^4-t^2 dt$$
$$ = -2(\dfrac{t^5} {5} - \dfrac{t^3}{3} + C$$ 
C = constant

$$ = -\dfrac{2}{5}(1+\dfrac{1}{x})^\dfrac{5}{2}+\dfrac{2}{3}(1+\dfrac{1}{x})^\dfrac{3}{2} + C$$

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\int \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {x^{7/2}} dx$$

$$ = \int \dfrac {\sqrt{x+1}} {x^{1/2}} \cdot \dfrac{dx} {x^{3}}$$

$$ = \int \sqrt{1+\dfrac 1 x} \cdot \dfrac{dx} {x^{3}}$$

Take $t^2 = 1 + \dfrac 1 x$

and note that $ \dfrac 1 x = t^2 - 1$

**More Hint**:

$t^2 = 1 + \dfrac 1 x$

$\implies 2tdt = -\dfrac 1 {x^2}dx$

$\implies 2t(1-t^2)dt = \dfrac 1 {x^3}dx$

Comment: @IndyZa, getting it?

Comment: Yeah I got it now Thanks Parth Thakkar :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \sqrt{x+1}/x^{7/2} dx=\int\frac{1}{x^3} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} dx$$
$1+\frac{1}{x}=t$ then $\frac{1}{x^2}dx=-dt $ and $\frac{1}{x}={t-1}$
$$\int\frac{1}{x^3} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} dx=\int\frac{1}{x} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}} \frac{dx}{x^2}=-\int(t-1)\sqrt {t}dt=\int (t^{1/2}-t^{3/2})dt$$